# Error loading file into content manager on demand using ODWEK

Tags: java, db2-content-manager

I'm trying to load an AFP document into Content Manager On Demand 9.5 using the bundled version of ODWEK.  I'm trying to follow this example showing its use:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21686382

My code is currently:

```
 ODServer odServer;
 ODConfig odConfig;
  System.setProperty("java.library.path", "/opt/ibm/ondemand/V9.5/www");
      odConfig = new ODConfig
         (ODConstant.PLUGIN,
               ODConstant.APPLET,
               null,
               200,
               "/applets",
               "ENU",
               "/home/pete",
               "/home/pete",
               4);
 odServer = new ODServer(odConfig);
 odServer.initialize("Logon.java");
 odServer.setPort(1445);
 odServer.logon("server.hostname", "user", "password");
 File file = new File("insure.afp");
 Hashtable<String,String> idxs = new Hashtable<>();
 idxs.put("CardNumber", "6969696969696969");
 idxs.put("CustomerName", "CMOD is cool");
 idxs.put("StatementDate", "2012-01-01");
 idxs.put("StatementType", "S");
 odServer.loadInit();
 odServer.loadAddDoc(1, idxs, file); 
 odServer.loadCommit("GoldCardsAG", "GoldCardsAafp");
 odServer.logoff( );
 odServer.terminate( );
```

I've confirmed that GoldCardsAG is the correct Application Group and GoldCardsAafp is the correct applName.

The error I get is:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.ibm.edms.od.ODException: Failed to commit Load. Please consult the System Log for additional information.
RC = 2096
Message = The server failed while storing a document
    at com.ibm.edms.od.ODServer.loadCommit(ODServer.java:3230)
    at Logon.putFileBatch(Logon.java:47)
    at Logon.main(Logon.java:34)
```

The line above that the exception is occurring at is:

`odServer.loadCommit("GoldCardsAG", "GoldCardsAafp");`

I've enabled full trace, here's whats appearing in arswww.trace:

```
10844:140062709262080 07/06/2016 13:07:56:926797 FLOW arscsvdc.c(2633)CsvAddStoreDoc:Return csv_rc=9,CSV_RC_MISC_ERROR csv_msgid=15,CSV_MSG_SERVER_FAILED_DOC_STO
10844:140062709262080 07/06/2016 13:07:56:926811 FLOW ars3wapi.C(515)apiP_setReturnCodeAndMessage:Enter
10844:140062709262080 07/06/2016 13:07:56:926833 FLOW ars3wcom.C(1174)CmGuiGetString:Enter
10844:140062709262080 07/06/2016 13:07:56:926858 ERROR ars3wapi.C(7807)Java_com_ibm_edms_od_ArsWWWInterface_apiStoreDoc:Current state rtn.RC=9 extId=2096 pMsg=The server failed while storing a document
10844:140062709262080 07/06/2016 13:07:56:926863 FLOW ars3wapi.C(591)apiP_setReturnCodeAndMessage:Return
10844:140062709262080 07/06/2016 13:07:56:926878 FLOW ars3wapi.C(7856)Java_com_ibm_edms_od_ArsWWWInterface_apiStoreDoc:Return session id=140062577532816 (rc)=1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix was to add the following 2 params in ars.cfg within the CMOD config folder:

```
ARS_DOWNLOAD_DIR=/tmp
ARS_DOWNLOAD_TMP_DIR=/tmp
```